# Problem in extracting a specific text (request token for the auto trader program)

Tags: python, string

I am developing a python project for algo trading , in that i had to generate a request token for authentication purposes. the token can be taken can be acquired from a url from the broker site. the url look like this. i have extracted the url using selenium.

```
https://zerodha.com/?request_token=**JZhT0vAv6L0ox9ZQdZCWhTWNUGLiLwXr**&action=login&status=success
```

The highlighted alphanumeric codes are the request token. I have used below code to extract it

```py
My_url = 'https://zerodha.com/request_token=JZhT0vAv6L0ox9ZQdZCWhTWNUGLiLwXr&action=login&status=success'
print(My_url)
print(type(My_url))
A_strip= My_url.strip('https://zerodha.com/?request_token=')
print(A_strip)
request_token = A_strip.strip('&action=login&status=success')
print(request_token)
print(len(request_token))
```

The expected output is a 32 Character text :  `JZhT0vAv6L0ox9ZQdZCWhTWNUGLiLwXr`

but the code working  differently every time. example  refer the below code

```py
My_url = 'https://zerodha.com/?request_token=HF4Bp4umtdFeC5n50auCA3DBim4N1Sto&action=login&status=success'
A_strip= My_url.strip('https://zerodha.com/?request_token=')
request_token = A_strip.strip('&action=login&status=success')
print(request_token)
print(len(request_token))
```

the output of the above expected to be `HF4Bp4umtdFeC5n50auCA3DBim4N1Sto` but i am getting `HF4Bp4umtdFeC5n50auCA3DBim4N1S`, a 30 character text output.

Except the token , the rest of url part is same. i am confused how it genarating diff values everytime. kindly help me out of it

Comment: please use ``` and add new line and place your code in between so that we can read it easily

Answer (score 0):

`.strip()` is used to remove leading/trailing characters. What you provide as argument is not the sequence to be removed but a set of characters.

Since `t` and `o` are in the sequence you provided they're removed from the tail of your string as they're considered trailing characters. Removing stops at `S` because this letter is not in your provided set.

If your token started with something else than `H`, ex. `a` or `c` etc. it would also get removed from the front, as it would be considered a leading character.

To solve you can either use regular expressions or simply slice the string, since you know the length of your start and end.

```
My_url = 'https://zerodha.com/?request_token=HF4Bp4umtdFeC5n50auCA3DBim4N1Sto&action=login&status=success'
prefix = 'https://zerodha.com/?request_token='
suffix = '&action=login&status=success'

token = My_url[len(prefix):-len(suffix)]
print(token, len(token))
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I have solved the issue with this below code                

``` 
Func = My_url.find('token')
Func =  Func+6
Request_token = My_url[Func:(Func+32)]
print(Request_token) 

```